# how do you run multiple scenarios (in the same or different feature files) without starting app instance cucumber jvm?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, jemmyfx

My setup closes the app instance when I run multiple scenarios, either in the same feature file or different feature files. Is there a way to run scenarios back-to-back without restarting the java app instance?

Answer (score 0):

This information is not enough to understand what is happening. 
But I reckon you should have something in your @After tags. If you have, delete the @After tags or quit methods in it.